# Boost.Asio how to send a client certificate to the server?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to send a client certificate with a REST call made by the [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/). Unfortunately, the cpprestsdk doesn't support that. However, it does allow access to the underlying framework, which is Boost.Asio for non-Windows platforms.

So my next questions is: how to set a client certificate in Boost.Asio?

Edit: The post [boost asio SSL two way authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342971/boost-asio-ssl-two-way-authentication) didn't help me, it only shows how to verify the server cert on the client-side, and on how to verify a client cert  on the server-side. It does not show me how to send a client cert in the first place.

Comment: I don't think the posted "duplicate" is indeed a duplciate. It only answers the question on how to verify the server cert on the client side and on how to verify the client cert on the server side. It says nothing about how to send a client cert to the server in the first place. Am I missing something?

Comment: ASIO is socket layer library. Sockets don't really do anything but send/receive bytes. REST in contrast is a methodology for defining protocols. You probably mean HTTP. For HTTP(S) try looking at the boost beast project.

Comment: WinTLS is windows only, but it has some examples for certificate handling, they should help you understand better. http://wintls.dev/. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Tiger4Hire: I have a solution for Windows, but the cpprestsdk is using Boost.Asio under the hoods for cross-platform, I need a solution for Linux to send a client certificate with Boost.Asio.

Comment: @Tiger4Hire: ASIO provides SSL streams, so it must have a possibility to send a client certificate somehow...

Comment: Not in the way that you mean. A client does not need a certificate to connect to a server. SSL/TLS and other encryption methods need to exchange a "symmetric-key", which is how the real communication is done. A server will normally not require a certificate to do that (they allow connection from ANY machine). They will use some other method to ensure the identity of the user, once a secure connection is established. This is normally name/password/TFA, etc. The exchange of the symmetric key is done via the "handshake".

Comment: Here is some code that I edited from the WinTLS project to support non-boost-asio. Note the connection phase only checks that the server certificate is valid, it never sets a client certificate.  https://github.com/creativedisassembly/boost-wintls/blob/master/examples/asio-only/https_client.cpp

Comment: Dude, client certifciate authentication is a thing, it's not the 0815 thing, but it is a thing. Please don't tell me, that there is no such thing *grr*

Comment: Sure it's a thing, It's not a normal flow, but it's a thing. I was confused because you started going on about REST. The certificate gets there through the SSL/TLS handshake. It has nothing to do with REST. If it's like the s-channel version, it's just a blob that the SSL layer makes. the socket layer sends it during the handshake. So the link that was suggested should be all you need, the handshake() function does the lifting.

Comment: Or maybe I should say "it does the lifting as long as the context is correctly configured, before the handshake", which maybe is where you are stuck?

Comment: This diagram shows where it fits. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Steps-of-the-SSL-handshake-and-messages_fig1_270574368